# Issues cross compiling unixODBC

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, cross-compiling, libtool, unixodbc

I am on a Mac, and I am having libtool linking issues when trying to compile unixODBC for arm7 (for me to use in iOS). I downloaded [unixODBC from their website](ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.1.tar.gz) and I use the following script to configure it and make it.

```
#!/bin/sh

# unset some shell variables
unset CC
unset CFLAGS
unset CPP

# make arm target
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2
export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk"
export CPP=/usr/bin/cpp

./configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --host=arm-apple-darwin10 --target=armv7 --enable-static --disable-shared

make all
```

./configure runs just fine, but during the `make all` it breaks. I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_lt_libltdlc_LTX_preloaded_symbols", referenced from:
      _lt_dlinit in libodbc.a(libltdlc_la-ltdl.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

I narrowed down the error to when the `make all` is run in the **exe** directory, specifically when the following command is run

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -pthread -o isql isql.o ../DriverManager/libodbc.la ../extras/libodbcextraslc.la
```

I'm not quite sure why it fails. I have checked that the `lt_dlinit` function does exist, and from what I can tell, everything is being done correctly. However, my experience using libtool is non-existent and my experience addressing linker issues is not extensive.

Any help is appreciated, and I can provide any additional information if necessary. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth running

libtoolize --copy --ltdl

At the root of the unixODBC build tree to copy in your local version of libtool

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that didn't work. I ran it before running my script, but when the `make all` starts, I get this error:

`libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.2.6b. You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2 and run autoconf again.` Any other suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: When I have to build stuff on the Mac using autotools, I usually just install the latest stable GNU autotools.  Usually the autotools installed with a particular version of OS X are too ancient to actually _use_ on that version of OS X, especially GNU libtool, which seems to be broken with some regularity.